# How to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) from SQL Server Agent Job to an Oracle Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, odbc

I have an SQL Server that uses SQL Server Agent.
In that Agent I have some jobs that need to connect to another Oracle Server through ODBC.
I've added a System DSN as an ODBC Data Source (32-bit).
I have a tnsnames.ora with the correct connection string since my connection is successful from ODBC Data Source.
The job must have wrong connection string but I don't know what it could be.

Connection String used in the Job:    `Dsn=SISF_MYDNS;uid=MyId;pwd=MyPwd;dbq=MyDb;dba=W;apa=T;exc=F;fen=T;qto=T;frc=10;fdl=10;lob=T;rst=T;btd=F;bnf=F;bam=IfAllSuccessful;num=NLS;dpm=F;mts=T;mdi=F;csr=F;fwc=F;fbs=64000;tlo=O;mld=0;oda=F`

ODBC Data Source
[image: ODBC Data Source]

TNS names
[image: tnsnames]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL Server was looking for a 64 bit ODBC and I only added a 32 bit ODBC Driver.
After creating a 64 bit ODBC with the same configurations as the 32 bit driver, I was able to connect with no problems.